# Textbox Setfocus VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint, setfocus

I'm on a Powerpoint VBA now, and trying to create a simple log in system
And I want to set focus to TextBox2 when I click TAB key on my keyboard if I'm focused on TextBox1.
This is my code.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
ByVal Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = 9 Then
TextBox2.SetFocus
End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

End Sub
```

What's the problem?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this at all. Just set the `TabIndex` properly for the two textbox controls, and then pressing Tab in TextBox1 will automatically set focus to TextBox2 with zero code from you.

Comment: Ken's correct.  But you'll also want to make sure that the text box's TabKeyBehavior property is set to FALSE.  If FALSE, the tab key will move you through the controls on the form whose TabSTop property is true.  If TRUE, it allows the text box to accept tabs as it does any other character.